# Different x axis for ggplot facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I would like to know if it is possible to create a ggplot with facet and different x axis?

My data looks like this

```
    id value group
1:   A    81    X1
2:   B   232    X1
3:   C    34    X1
4:   D    52    X1
5:  0%   242    X2
6: 10%    13    X2
7: 20%   291    X2
8: 30%    45    X2
```

so my current code looks like this

```
myplot <- ggplot(mydata, aes(id, group = group)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = value, fill = id), stat="sum") + 
  facet_grid(~group) 
myplot
```

Which creates 2 plots with all id values for each plot and adds for group X1 value 0 for 0%,10%...

I would like to have two plot with different x axis which i could achieve with just doing two filtered plots but is it possible with facet?

Comment: Does adding `scales = "free_x"` to `facet_grid()` achieve what you want?

Comment: Yes it does! Thanks a lot @Z.Lin !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [@Z.Lin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8449629/z-lin) suggested adding `scales = "free_x"` to `facet_grid()` solve my problem